# Strange htaccess url rewrite behavior

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess

I want to rewrite `example.com/login` into `example.com/login.php`
this used to work on my old server as I was using this rule in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [L]
```

when I migrated to a new server, this specific rule has stopped from working, but if I change `login` to `loginx` for example

```
RewriteRule ^loginx$ login.php [L]
```

the rule works and I see the login page when I go to `example.com/loginx`

also, if I change the filename, the rule starts to work too

```
RewriteRule ^login$ loginx.php [L]
```

It looks like if the rule and the file has the same name (login in this case) the rule doesn't work for a reason I can't understand, does anybody knows why this happens and how to deal with it?

Here's the full `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^users$ users.php [L]
RewriteRule ^profile$ me.php [L]
```

the problem happens with the `users` too (because the file has the name as the URL)
the `profile` rule works correctly.

Comment: Works with this tester: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=eaac3d98-5dd7-586f-9122-20dd77abee0e

Comment: Do you have access to apache .conf files?

Comment: yes I do, I want to add that all the other rewrite rules are working except this one

Comment: Please post the entire .htaccess, perhaps there is a conflicting rule

Comment: Disable `MultiViews`, it is most often the culprit in situations like these.

Comment: thank you very much, that has solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working thanks to 04FS
I just added

```
Options -Multiviews
```

in the top of my htaccess file

Comment: What version of Apache are you on? Did you have any other files whose basename were also `login` or `users`? (Ordinarily, with MultiViews enabled, `login.php` and `users.php` should have still been called, since this is what MultiViews does - but the two affected mod_rewrite directives would have effectively been bypassed.)

Answer (score -1):

Did you add `RewriteEngine On` above it in the .htaccess?

Comment: the rewrite engine is on yes, all the other rewrite rules are working and the rule itself starts to work if I change something in the word "login"